# Как сохранить чат пользователя в PyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, telebot

Я делаю бота с решением химических реакций. То есть бот задаёт вопрос, а пользователь должен написать реакцию. И если перезапускать бота, то он перестанет реагировать на ответы до тех пор, пока пользователь не запросит заново тему. Как сохранять последнее сообщение, которое высылал бот для каждого пользователя, чтобы при перезагрузке бот смог отреагировать на ответ?[image: пример не реагирования на ответ пользователя(бот должен был ответить, что ответ неверный)]

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать концепцию стейт-машины, то есть после каждого сообщения боту присваивается некое состояние, которое не меняется до определенного условия. По сути, это и есть сохранение последнего ответа бота. Много библиотек на это тему, а еще можно попробовать саму реализовать что-то похожее.

Comment: Дополнил бы, что в pytelegrambotapi - state() отсутствует. Автору требуется асинхронная библиотека AIOgram.

Comment: вот с AIOgram были проблемы, что бот не реагировал на ответы пользователя и не высылал следующий вопрос. Поэтому код был переписан на PyTelegramBotAPI